# Convert ratings in stars in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.1) in which I want to display an average rating returns from a view inside the Django template.

Here's What I have tried so far:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('GD', 'Graphic & Design'),
        ('DM', 'Digital Marketing'),
        ('WT', 'Writing & Translation'),
        ('VA', 'Video & Animation'),
        ('MA', 'Music & Audio'),
        ('PT', 'Programming & Tech'),
        ('FL', 'Fun & Lifestyle'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class GigReview(models.Model):
    RATING_RANGE = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rates')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_RANGE,)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
def home(request):
    gigs = Gig.objects.filter(status=True).annotate(avg_review=Avg('rates__rating'))
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'gigs': gigs})
```

So, now every `gig` has an average rating and I want to display stars as the rating inside the template.

**From `home.html`:**

```
{% for gig in gigs %}
   <div data-marker-id="59c0c8e33b1527bfe2abaf92" class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 border-0 shadow">
             <div style="background-image: url(/media/{{ gig.photo }}); min-height: 200px;"
                                 class="card-img-top overflow-hidden dark-overlay bg-cover">
                   <a href="{% url 'gig-detail' gig.id %}" class="tile-link"></a>
                    <div class="card-img-overlay-bottom z-index-20"></div>
                    <div class="card-img-overlay-top d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="badge badge-transparent badge-pill px-3 py-2">{{ git.category }}</div>
                     <a href="javascript: void();" class="card-fav-icon position-relative z-index-40">
                      <svg class="svg-icon text-white">
                                            <use xlink:href="#heart-1"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                     <h6 class="text-shadow"><a href="{% url 'gig-detail' gig.id %}"
                                                           style="text-decoration: none; color: black">
                                    {{ gig.title }}</a></h6>
                                <p class="mb-2 text-xs" id="stars">
                                    {{ gig.avg_review }}
                                    {% if gig.avg_review is not None %}
                                        {{ gig.avg_review }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star text-gray-300"></i>
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-sm text-muted mb-3">{{ gig.description|slice:"20" }}...</p>
                                <p class="text-sm text-muted text-uppercase mb-1">
                                    <span>By <a href="{% url 'profile' gig.user.username %}"
                                                class="text-dark">{{ gig.user }}</a></span>
                                    <span class="float-right"><b class="text-shadow text-lg"
                                                                 style="color: black;">${{ gig.price }}</b></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

So, how Can I display the average rating of every `gig` as stars filled by the rating?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: doesn't `gig.avg_review` work?

Comment: yes, it prints the average rating like `3.5` or `None` if gig is not rated yet!

Comment: so the point is to display stars instead of numbers, isn't it?

Comment: yes, exactly, you are right!

Comment: If so, I have used [django-star-rating](https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings) or you could use several JS libraries as [star-rating](https://nashio.github.io/star-rating-svg/demo/)

Comment: I have tried django-star-rating already, didn't worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191000/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-abdul-rehman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several alternatives like using [django-star-rating](https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings) or you could use several JS libraries as [star-rating](https://nashio.github.io/star-rating-svg/demo/) or [starability](https://github.com/LunarLogic/starability).

I will provide my solution using starability though it could be primarily based opinion.

**In your template:**

Include the styles in the `head` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/starability-all.min.css"/>
```

and use the following:

```
<fieldset class="starability-result mx-auto" data-rating="{{ gig.avg_review }}">
    Rated: {{ gig.avg_review }} stars
</fieldset>
```

You might probably need to cast `gig.avg_review` to an integer, and I suggest you do it in the view.

The main problem of starability is that it doesn't have support for half stars, but if you don't care too much about it, you can use the following to round your average

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 0)'
```

Now apply it to your query:

```
gigs = Gig.objects.filter(status=True).annotate(avg_review=Round(Avg('rates__rating')))
```

For more information, in case you decide to use it, I encourage you to check starability's [documentation](https://github.com/LunarLogic/starability).

Comment: How can we retrieve the rating back from templates if someone gave a rating? I know the javascript part, but what should I look for?